# Setting Visualforce page URL different from file name

Tags: visualforce, url

How to set a Visualforce page URL that is different from a file name?

At the moment my VF page URLs are the same as the file names:
`MyPage.page` URL will be `/apex/MyPage`

How to leave file name as is (for example `MyPage.page`) but change the URL to different one (for example `/apex/YourPage`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution would be to create a new "dummy" visualforce page with a name you wished ("YourPage") that will redirect user to another page.

Redirect using javasript. Disadvantage of this solution is that a seocond page name appears on the browser url.

```
<apex:page>
    <script>
        window.location.href = '/apex/MyPage';
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

The second solution with an `apex:include`:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:include pageName="MyPage" />
</apex:page>
```

Here a name of the first page ("YourPage") is not disappearing from the URL so this is preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in the context of Sites, you can utilize the [URL Rewriter](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm).